# Media Storage and Media Picker in Orchard CMS

Tags: storage, orchardcms, media, orchardcms-1.7

crosspost: https://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/471948

We just noticed that some files listed when visiting folders under Media Storage are not always listed in the Media Picker modal. I did some tinkering myself and found out that if you upload files via **Media Storage -> Select Folder -> Add Media**, it doesn't get listed at all, as opposed to going onto **Media Picker -> Select Folder -> Import**.

Correct me if I'm wrong but I remember one of the changes in 1.7 is that media is now treated as a Content Type as opposed to having the picker just crawl through folders. Does this have anything to do with it? (i.e. Media Storage just uploads the file, Media Picker import adds the CT and lists it)

Any piece of information would be highly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got this right: media storage is an obsolete feature that should not be used once you've switched to the media library. It's really the old module, that manages only files, not content items.

Comment: Which module should I disable? Sebastian says that I should disable the Media Module if I had the Media Library active, but the Media Picker field is dependent on Media. Or is the new picker the Media Library Picker field?

Comment: Yes, Media Library Picker replaces Media Picker.